# PHP and calculation with hours

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have a little logic problem.
I have this:

```
$y=2014;
$m=05;
$d=22;
$d2=$d+1;

$sunset=17:52;
$sunrise=05:44;
```

I have some events that occurs during the days 22 and 23, but I want select only the ones that happen between $sunset and $sunrise.

Ho can I say something like this:

```
if($event [$sunset<BETWEEN>$sunrise]){
//show something;
}
```

? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create DateTime objects and then it's as simple as calculating the difference in time.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Example:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Comment: I was thinking, now, that I can work with the julian day too, may be can be easier.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime()` as they are comparable which makes this easy:

```
$sunrise = new DateTime('2014-05-22 05:44');
$sunset  = new DateTime('2014-05-23 17:52');
$good    = new DateTime('2014-05-22 18:00');
$bad     = new DateTime('2014-05-23 18:00');
if ($good > $sunrise && $good < $sunset) {
    echo '$good is good';
}
if ($bad > $sunrise && $bad < $sunset) {
    echo '$bad is good';
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/T7s4ZM)